# Write command output to file without using redirection

Tags: bash, sed, io-redirection

I have to write a small bash script that writes some information into a file. However, the script is going to be called from a place that does not support redirection operators (RTM). Since I can not use the redirection operators. I've tried something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
busers_var=$(busers -w name)
sed -i 'T a/"$busers_var"' alert.out
```

I get the error:

```
sed: can't find label for jump to `a/"$busers_var"'
```

Or if I use:

```
sed -i "T a/$busers_var" alert.out
```

I get:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 25: unknown command: `J'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is rtm? I assume it's not Remember The Milk?

Comment: Unix shells offer redirections. If you are trying to circumvent a restricted `bash`, then since you can not execute any arbitrary command, it would be better that you tell us first what commands you have at your disposal: what is the content of your `PATH`? If there are unusual directories in it, what is their content?

Comment: Why can't you use redirection? There's no version of bash that doesn't support redirection. If you have some arbitrary constraint, you need to explain what this constraint is. “Write a bash script” and “place that does not support redirection operators” is contradictory.

Comment: And why are you using the ``T`` command in ``sed``? What do you think you are doing?

Answer (score 7):

If `busers -w name` is the command in question, then try `tee`:

```
busers -w name | tee /path/to/output
```

Perhaps adding stderr:

```
busers -w name 2>&1 | tee /path/to/output
```

Or use `ed`:

```
touch output; ed -s output <<< $'r !busers -w name\nwq'
```

Or use [`sort`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) to "merge already sorted files; do not sort", combined with its `-o output` option:

```
buser -w name | sort -m -o output
```

Comment: Just realized that a here-string is probably cheating, but I'll leave it in case it's allowed.